# bitmap- error: cannot find symbol method wrap

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm running into this error:

> error: cannot find symbol method wrap(byte[])
>   Error is in the last line of this parto of my main code:

```
public SparseArray<Face> detect(Frame frame) {

            YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(frame.getGrayscaleImageData().array(), ImageFormat.NV21, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight(), null); // Create YUV image from byte[]
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, frame.getMetadata().getWidth(), frame.getMetadata().getHeight()), 100, byteArrayOutputStream);// Convert YUV image to Jpeg
            byte[] jpegArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegArray, 0, jpegArray.length); // Convert Jpeg to Bitmap
            Frame outputbmp = new Frame.Builder().setImageData(bmp.wrap(yuvImage.getYuvData()), yuvImage.getWidth(), yuvImage.getHeight(), yuvImage.getYuvFormat()).setRotation(Frame.ROTATION_270).build();
```

Comment: What is the requirement actually?

Comment: I would to use Bitmap bmp in last line and the use it to do image processing of face detection box. Need I to use outputbmp or could I use bmp?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method in the Bitmap class. Please refer to this
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap

Comment: ok thanks. what I need to change? I would use Bitmap bmp in the last line. what's wrong?